python send InMemoryUploadedFile to requests.request
In postmen I send data like this:

My python code is:
headers = {
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=974767299852498929531610575",
    }


response = requests.request(
            "POST",
            LINK,
            headers=headers,
            data={
                'product_id': 1,
                'product_images': [file, ]
              }
)

Where file has InMemoryUploadedFile format. But I've got error.
Also I've tried
file = my_file.file.getvalue()

But still the error. How can I fix my cod and get 200 status? Any ideas?

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

maybe you need file= instead of data=?

BTW: as I remember postman has function to generate code for different languages and modules - and it can generate code for python requests.

What error?  Please show the traceback.

error just 400 status code and {'detail': 'There was an error parsing the body'}

and you should show it in question, not in comment. We can't run your code we can't see your computer and we can't read in your mind - you have to show all details in question.

BTW: I checked my local postman and on the right side it has button </> (with tips Code) which open window to generate code. For Python it can generate code for requests and http.client

BTW: for tests you can also use URL https://httpbin.org/post and it will send you back what it gets from you - all headers, body, etc. And it allows to compare request from Postman and request from own code - and it allows to see if code creates correct request.

Postman (installed on local computer) on the right side has button </> (with description Code) to generate Code snippets and it can generate code for different languages and modules.
For Python it can generate code for requests or http.client

Here is code generated by Postman for requests
import requests

url = "https://httpbin.org/post"

payload={'product_id': '1'}
files=[
  ('product_images',('rect.png',open('/home/furas/images/rect.png','rb'),'image/png'))
]
headers = {}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)

print(response.text)

I can't test it with Django object InMemoryUploadedFile but I think it may need this object directly in place of open() - if only InMemoryUploadedFile has function .read()
files=[
  ('product_images', ('rect.png', your_InMemoryUploadedFile ,'image/png'))
]

Should works also to put data from object your_InMemoryUploadedFile.read()
files=[
  ('product_images', ('rect.png', your_InMemoryUploadedFile.read() ,'image/png'))
]

Eventually it may need to create io.BytesIO() and put data in this object - and use directly this object instead of open(). Probably it should work for both my_file.file or my_file.file.getvalue()

For tests you can use URL https://httpbin.org/post and it will send you back what it gets from you - all headers, body, etc. And it allows to compare request from Postman and request from own code - and it allows to see if code creates correct request.

Thanks, I fount this option in postmen. But still the question is how to use it for InMemoryUploadedFile?

I think requests may need directly InMemoryUploadedFile (not .getvalue()) in place of open() in files= - if only InMemoryUploadedFile has function .read(). Eventually it may need to use io.BytesIO() with data from InMemoryUploadedFile and set this object instead of open() (without .getvalues())

Thats weird, but it works only without Content-Type in headers
    url = "http://some-url.com/"
    file = my_file.read() 

        payload = {'product_id': '1'}
        files = [
            ('product_images', ('image2.png', file, 'image/png')),
        ]
        headers = {
            # 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }

        response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)

        print(response.text)


files= should automatically add this header - and it should set correct value boundary= because it has to be the same value as inside body. You can't set it on your own - you would have to manually create body and use the same value as in header.

BTW: if you send it to https://httpbin.org/post then it sends you back all headers - and you can see that it adds Content-Type always with different boundary=. And if you check response.request.body then you see that it starts (every value - even product_id) with this value from boundary= (with -- before number, and also with --after last number - to show end of data) If you set manually header withboundary=` then it doesn't match to data in body.
